# How to get logical path in a makefile?

Tags: makefile

I want to use the same files in different symbol linked path and check the different logical path to set different DEFINE FLAG.

But I can't use pwd to get the **logical path.**

Help me. Thanks!

---

What I want to do:

1. suppose physical path is ~/src/
2. `ln ~/src/ ~/src_a/`
3. if I go to the logical path(~/src_a) and do make, I hope it can check the logical path. If the logical path is src_a, add a debug flag.

Comment: I cannot understand your question. Could you give an example?

Comment: @Beta I add details on the question. Thanks.

Comment: If you "go to the logical path" (which I take to mean `cd ~/src_a`, then the working directory is `~/src/`. *How you got there* is not remembered, except perhaps as a command in the history stack. If you want to set a debug flag, you can do so explicitly when you invoke Make.